# generate report on keyword rank

Tags: matomo

On the detailed visitor log piwik is able to some the position the keyword was listed on a search engine.

eg:

[image]

Where is this stored in the database? I have been looking around for it but not able to find anything in the logs table nor the visitors table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Google specific. The rank in the search result is actually submitted by Google in the referrer as the `cd=` param. There's a [breakdown of all the available params](http://www.t75.org/2012/06/deconstructing-googles-url-search-parameters/) available.

The visitor log report in Piwik just extracts this information from the referrer URL that is stored for the visit. Have a look at the [source of the Live plugin](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/browser/trunk/plugins/Live/Visitor.php#L352):

```
function getKeywordPosition()
{
    if($this->getRefererType() == 'search'
        && strpos($this->getRefererName(), 'Google') !== false)
    {
        $url = @parse_url($this->details['referer_url']);
        if(empty($url['query']))
        {
            return null;
        }
        $position = Piwik_Common::getParameterFromQueryString($url['query'], 'cd');
        if(!empty($position))
        {
            return $position;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```